# bestSum - Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the problem bestSum which basically finds the min amount of elements that add up to the target value, the following seems to be working fine,

Example output, bestSum(10, new int[]{1, 2, 5}) should pring [5,5).

```
static List<Integer> bestSumNoDp(int target, int[] nums) {
    if (target == 0) return new ArrayList<>();
    if (target < 0) return null;

    List<Integer> shortest = null;
    for (Integer num : nums) {
        List<Integer> list = bestSumNoDp(target-num, nums);
        if (list != null) {
            list.add(num);
            if (shortest == null || shortest.size() > list.size())
                shortest = list;
        }
    }
    return shortest;
}
```

I'm having an issue when I try to implement the DP version, I noticed when I print the cache, the print that has a "Top", an extra element is being added, I can't figure out why, what I'm I doing wrong?

```
    static ArrayList bestSum(int target, int[] nums) {
        return bestSum(target, nums, new ArrayList[target+1]);
    }

    static ArrayList<Integer> bestSum(int target, int[] nums, ArrayList<Integer>[] cache) {
        if (target == 0) return new ArrayList<>();
        if (target < 0) return null;
        //System.out.println("Top - Target " + target + " Cache " + cache[target]); //Debugging

        if (cache[target] != null) return cache[target];
        
        ArrayList<Integer> shortest = null;
        for (Integer num : nums) {
            ArrayList<Integer> list = bestSum(target-num, nums, cache);
            if (list != null) {
                list.add(num);
                if (shortest == null || shortest.size() > list.size())
                    shortest = list;
            }
        }

//        cache[target] = null;//
//        cache[target] = (ArrayList<Integer>) shortest.clone(); //Didn't help
//        cache[target] = shortest;//Didn't help
        cache[target] = new ArrayList<>(shortest);//this one also didn't work but kept it
        //System.out.println("Bottom - Target " + target + " Cache " + cache[target]);//Debugging

        return shortest;
    }
```

Comment: You are returning `cache[target]` to a function that immediately modifies it.  Perhaps `if (cache[target] != null) return cache[target].clone();` instead?

Comment: Trying it now...

Comment: Yup, that did the trick :), thanks @btilly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above by @btilly I need to do this,

```
(cache[target] != null) return cache[target].clone();
```